# Scripts compiled at runtime fail to invoke method with optional arguments

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, optional-parameters, csharpcodeprovider

We've added a feature for our users to write C# scripts for the application to execute, which are compiled and run at runtime.  The scripts may access an API we've exposed, and they're compiled/run by CSharpCodeProvider.

I find that the code compiled at runtime has problems when calling a method with optional arguments, e.g.:

```
public void BlackmailColonelMustard(int amount, string myAlias, bool tellHisWifeAnyway = true)
```

If the compiled-at-runtime script calls **BlackmailColonelMustard(10000, "Mr Boddy")**, the compiler complains that there's no overloaded method with only two arguments, rather than recognize the third parameter's default value.

Naturally it works fine when called from pre-compiled code.  Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Is it because VS2010 (even pre-.NET 4) is smart enough to compile code which uses optional parameters, but the .NET 3.5 runtime hasn't yet learned that trick?

Comment: If you're targetting .NET 3.5, it's possible that the `CSharpCodeProvider` uses C# 3.0 rules, which preclude the use of optional parameters.

Comment: I think I may be asking for trouble using default parameters anyway.  It should be safe enough if we implement IronPython (Python uses default parameter values) at some point, but I wonder if we'll want to implement another DLR language which doesn't play nicely with that approach.

Your comment may agree with this article: [Default Parameters Should Not Be Used](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182135.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Optional arguments have been introduced in C# 4.0. Set compiler version to 4.0 if possible:

```
Dictionary<string, string> options = new Dictionary<string, string>();
options.Add("CompilerVersion", "v4.0");
CSharpCodeProvider provider = new CSharpCodeProvider(options);
```

Comment: That might work locally, but I don't think I can compile it that way, as the deployment target machines run .NET 3.5, but not necessarily .NET 4.0.  I think I've just confused a neat VS2010 feature with a .NET feature.

Comment: There is no other solution. If you really want to use C# 4.0 features, then you need to upgrade the framework on deployment machines to version 4 (or higher). If upgrade is not possible, then I'm afraid you have to abandon using these features.

Comment: @wilee It's not a VS2010 feature, it's a C# 4.0 feature. .Net doesn't actually have optional arguments. If you compile your code with the .Net 4.0 version of `CSharpCodeProvider`, that should be able to use C# 4.0 (because .Net 4.0 includes C# 4.0 compiler).

Comment: .NET always had optional arguments but the C# compiler only supports them since C# 4.0.